# Force HTTPS using .htaccess - stuck in redirect loop

Tags: redirect, htaccess, ssl, https

My Wordpress website is located at example.com/wordpress and I need everything inside to be accessible only using SSL.

I've created a .htaccess rule that redirects http -> https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/wordpress/directory/$1 [R,L]
```

After implementing this rule the website is inaccessible as it is stuck in a redirect loop.

What am I doing wrong?

My Wordpress .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/directory/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/directory/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a late answer but this works for me:

Change the RewriteCond to this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
```

Should be like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: This finally worked for me. Can anyone explain *why* this RewriteCond would work when `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` doesn't?

Comment: In some case, If https version of the site is not configured via Apache ModSSL it doesn't set %{HTTPS} variable

Answer (score 2):

Without being an htaccess expert, I'd say you're missing a `RewriteCond` - A condition.

Check if it's on port 80. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/wordpress/directory/$1 [R,L]
```

**UPDATE:**

After seeing your updated question, with the full .htaccess - I'd do this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/directory/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/directory/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/wordpress/directory/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Having your condition and rule underneath Wordpress' standards.

Comment: Adding it to my .htaccess didn't help, I am experiencing the same redirect loop problem.

Comment: Can you copy your htaccess file then? Post it in the question - I'll edit my answer to another attempt then!

Comment: Try `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` instead of the server_port condition.

Comment: Didn't work and my whole .htaccess file is already in the question :)

Comment: Oh.. Where's the standard Wordpress htaccess things then?

Comment: If nothing else - Try including the `RewriteEngine On` again, above my updated answer!

Comment: Hmm, maybe that is the problem - I have nothing else but this in my .htaccess

Comment: Restored default .htaccess, but the issue is still not fixed. Update my question.

Comment: Updated my answer - Just combine the two then?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Source https://www.godaddy.com/help/redirect-http-to-https-automatically-8828

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

or for just a single page

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} directory
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/directory/$1 [R,L]
```

or you can add this php to a particular file

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || !$_SERVER['HTTPS']) { // if request is not secure, redirect to secure url
$url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

header('Location: ' . $url);
exit;
}
```

or combine the wordpress rewrite rules with the SSL ones..

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/directory/index\.php[R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Web sites behind load balancers or reverse proxies that support `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` can be fixed by adding the **following code to the `wp-config.php` file**, above the require_once call:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```

**or by using a plugin**

Add into WordPress plugins folder on your website, then activate it in the Plugins admin

```
<? /* Plugin Name: Set headers */
if (stripos(get_option('siteurl'), 'https://') === 0) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
    // add JavaScript detection of page protocol, and pray!
    add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'force_ssl_url_scheme_script');
}
function force_ssl_url_scheme_script() {
    ?>
    <script>
    if (document.location.protocol != "https:") {
        document.location = document.URL.replace(/^http:/i, "https:");
    }
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

*[Source](https://gist.github.com/krunalsojitra/b975043933bca9183f57581e45858949)*

It is working like

- `http://www.exmaple.com/blog/` **to** `https://www.exmaple.com/blog/`
- `http://www.exmaple.com/` **to** `https://www.exmaple.com/`